# titlesec: Want to remove section nums in TOC but not subsection

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, titlesec

Title says it all.

---

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[OR]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[OC]{\textsc{Jonathan W. Tooker}}
\fancyhead[EC]{\textsc{Levels of Aleph}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}


\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesection.}   {1em}{} \titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesubsection.}{1em}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Just use `\section` for your sub-section.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with the `titletoc` package, which interfaces nicely with `titlesec` (same author). To add some vertical space before each section in the TOC we flag the first one and add `\vspace{.5\baselineskip}` in the 'before' code of the section heading. Change this value to whatever you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newif\iffirst\firsttrue % to flag first TOC entry
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesection.}   {1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\titlecontents{section}
              [0em] 
              {\iffirst\global\firstfalse\else\vspace{.5\baselineskip}\fi\bfseries}
              {}
              {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
              {\hfill\contentspage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\subsection{Another one}
\section{A second section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  How can I add a little white space between the last subsection title and the next Section title?

Comment: @JonathanTooker I've updated the answer to add some vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesection.}   {1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S \thesubsection.}{1em}{}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  numwidth=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\gobble
]{tocline}{section}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\subsection{Another one}
\section{A second section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]